# Name of fantasy book from the late 1970s/early 80,

Tags: story-identification, books

The protagonist was a young human woman living in a society ruled by cat-like humanoids. She was a talented seamstress and embroiderer, and ended up selected to do custom work for one of the overlords.

As she was working on a particular commission, the overlord started to frequently visit her, raising concern with both her peers as well as his peers. It was clear they were developing a personal, possibly a romantic relationship

I moved just as I was about half-way into the book, and the book was lost in the move. It's decades later and I am still trying to remember the name of the book so I can finally finish it.

Comment: Sounds like it *could* be part of the man-kzin wars universe created by Larry Niven, but those were all short stories, if I’m not mistaken. Also those started in the late 80s.